# how to make the container div height fit window height but do no resize with window size

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code to create a page layout. I get the container div height fit to the window height, but when I resize the window height, all contents are squeezed together vertically. How could i fix the height and width of the container div?

```
 <style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
    }        

    #container {

        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 800px;  
        height:100vh;          
        background-color: azure;

    }

    #rw1 {
        height: 10vh;
        background-color: aliceblue;            
    }

    #rw2 {
        height: 80vh;
        background-color: #ff6a00;
    }

    #rw3 {
        height: 10vh;
        background-color: #808080;
    }
   </style>


   <div id="container">
       <div id="rw1"></div>
       <div id="rw2"></div>
       <div id="rw3"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean fix the height? You don't want the content to get squished together if the screen is shorter?

Comment: They squeeze, cus u used the 'vh' units, they work depending on viewport height. But, I don't get the whole question!

Comment: @JacobGray I mean when the window is maximum, the div fits the height of the screen, but when the windows size change, the content will not squeeze. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite an open-ended question but I think you'll probably want to experiment with media queries, spcifically using a combination of `max-width` and `max-height` as follows:

```
@media (max-height: 300px) {
     #rw1 {
        height: 33vh;
        background-color: aliceblue;            
    }
    #rw2 {
        height: 33vh;
        background-color: #ff6a00;
    }
    #rw3 {
        height: 33vh;
        background-color: #808080;
    }
}
```

Can also combine `max-width` / `max-height` as follows:

```
@media (max-width: 767px), (max-height: 300px) {
         #container {
            width: 750px;  
        }
         #rw1 {
            height: 33vh;
            background-color: aliceblue;            
        }
        #rw2 {
            height: 33vh;
            background-color: #ff6a00;
        }
        #rw3 {
            height: 33vh;
            background-color: #808080;
        }
    }
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9vwe255a/

Try resizing the Results pane in both width and height, you'll notice the div's change size according to the viewport.